# Does SQLite support CASE WHEN queries?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I intend give points based on the rank of a participant. For instance position 1 should be given 32 point, position 2 be given 31 points position 3 be given 30 points and so on...
The result is not comming. It is just returning '1' for any position. What could be wrong with the query? 
NOTE: The query works well with SQLExpress but when I use it with SQLite, it just returns 1 for all positions of the participants.
This is my SQLiteCommand query:

```
cn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO PARTICIPANT5(NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE,TITLE,YEAR,TOTAL,POSITION,POINTS) SELECT  DISTINCT NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE,TITLE ,YEAR,SUM(AVG) AS TOTAL, RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC) AS POSITION , CASE WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='1' THEN '32' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='2' THEN '31' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='3' THEN '30' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='4' THEN '29' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='5' THEN '28' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='6' THEN '27' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='7' THEN '26' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='8' THEN '25' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='9' THEN '24'  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='10' THEN '23' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='11' THEN '22' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='12' THEN '21'  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='13' THEN '20' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='14' THEN '19' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='15' THEN '18'  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='16' THEN '17' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='17' THEN '16' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='18' THEN '15' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='19' THEN '14' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='20' THEN '13' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='21' THEN '12'  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='22' THEN '11' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='23' THEN '10' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='24' THEN '9' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='25' THEN '8' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='26' THEN '7' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='27' THEN '6' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='28' THEN '5' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='29' THEN '4' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='30' THEN '3' WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)='31' THEN '2' ELSE '1' END POINTS FROM Average WHERE YEAR='" + textBox15.Text + "' AND CATEGORY = '" + textBox1.Text + "' GROUP BY NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE,TITLE,YEAR  ", cn);
int count3 = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Thank you !

Comment: you should use command parameters instead of using string concatenation to pass arguments. it leads to sql injections

Comment: @Irdis expound a bit. Thanks !

Comment: @Calvinceokeyo here is an article explaining how the injection attacks work and why it is a problem: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-injection-attacks

Comment: @Irdis my question was not on injection. It was about the workability of the query in question. Thank you !

Comment: I read your answer, If you had used parameters you wouldn't even had had problem with quotes. If you use it now there will be no reason to remove quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the problem was. Now it works like a charm !
The SQLite does not understand the single quotes in the query...
I have simply removed the all the single quotes. This is how it looks like.
 try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmd3 = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO PARTICIPANT5(NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE,TITLE,YEAR,TOTAL,POSITION,POINTS) SELECT  DISTINCT NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE,TITLE ,YEAR,SUM(AVG) AS TOTAL, RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC) AS POSITION , CASE WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=1 THEN 32 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=2 THEN 31 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=3 THEN 30 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=4 THEN 29 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=5 THEN 28 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=6 THEN 27 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=7 THEN 26 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=8 THEN 25 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=9 THEN 24  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=10 THEN 23 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=11 THEN 22 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=12 THEN 21  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=13 THEN 20 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=14 THEN 19 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=15 THEN 18  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=16 THEN 17 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=17 THEN 16 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=18 THEN 15 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=19 THEN 14 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=20 THEN 13 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=21 THEN 12  WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=22 THEN 11 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=23 THEN 10 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=24 THEN 9 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=25 THEN 8 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=26 THEN 7 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=27 THEN 6 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=28 THEN 5 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=29 THEN 4 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=30 THEN 3 WHEN RANK()OVER (ORDER BY SUM(AVG) DESC)=31 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END POINTS FROM Average WHERE YEAR='" + textBox15.Text + "' AND CATEGORY = '" + textBox1.Text + "' GROUP BY NAMES,SCHOOL,TYPE ,TITLE,YEAR  ", cn);
                    int count3 = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();

```
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```